# how set runtime background image in textview in android?

Tags: android, textview, back

i want to set runtime background in `textview` in android
here you can see i have a one `image` which is runtime set this is not fix so i want to change runtime background in `textview` and current location in text with different color

```
 holder.textmenu.setBackgroundDrawable(R.Drawable.imagename) // gives error
 holder.textmenu.setBackgroundColor(R.color.color_orange);`
```

[image]

Comment: can u post the logcat trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

holder.textmenu.setBackgroundResource(R.Drawable.imagename)

Comment: how can i change the style of text runtime because runtime is not provide propert textstyle when i Ctrl + Space i want to change from bold to normal

Answer (score 0):

To set an image as your textview backgrouhnd use `youtextview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourimage);`